# Using Oracle in select query

Tags: sql, oracle

Question: Given the CITY and COUNTRY tables, query the sum of the populations of all cities where the CONTINENT is 'Asia'.

City table contains fields: CountryCode, Population
Country table contains fields: Code, Continent
(CITY.CountryCode and COUNTRY.Code are matching key columns.)

I tried the following query: (I know this can be solved using Inner join)

```
Select sum(city.population) from city
where city.countrycode in (Select code from Country where continent = 'Asia')
```

Hacker rank gives following error:
ERROR at line 3: 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Your syntax look right, so what's the question - how to do it with an inner join?

Comment: Looks fine. Inner join would be fine too. And EXISTS.

Comment: Hackerrank gives following error: ERROR at line 3: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Also, @jarlh when do we use in and when do we use exist operation?

Comment: Maybe Hacker Rank requires an ending semicolon?  if this query were run in SQL developer it looks like it would work.

Comment: Yes, ; worked. This is stupid. I have an interview with Amazon data engineer role and have a sql test. Syntax for mysql/ oracle (ex. AS alias does not work in hackerrank portal) does not seem consistent on different forums. Any suggestion?

Comment: Also, what works faster: using the inner join or the query I have written? And why?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a semi colon?

Something along these lines......

Per city..........

```
SELECT City.Name, SUM(City.Population)
FROM City INNER JOIN Country ON Country.Code = City.CountryCode
WHERE
  Country.Continent = 'ASIA'
GROUP BY 
  City.Name;
```

Per Country & City

```
SELECT Country.Name, City.Name, SUM(City.Population)
FROM City INNER JOIN Country ON Country.Code = City.CountryCode
WHERE
  Country.Continent = 'ASIA'
GROUP BY 
  Country.Name, City.Name;
```

Just the Total for ASIA

```
SELECT SUM(City.Population)
FROM City INNER JOIN Country ON Country.Code = City.CountryCode
WHERE
  Country.Continent = 'ASIA';
```

Comment: I know this. My question is what is wrong with the query I have written?

Comment: Also, what works faster: using the inner join or the query I have written? And why?

Comment: That would depend on the amount of data in the tables.
Stick with the INNER JOIN, it will scale better as your tables grow.

Your original query will have to scan through the country table to find the continent....Imagine if you have a lot of countries in there.

Comment: From what I've read: it used to be that the "in" syntax would result in slower execution. Since Oracle 10 (I think) the wise folks at Oracle figured out that the "in" syntax is equivalent to a join and the optimizer now does that for you. The performance should be the same. Which you could check for yourself by experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

What we are doing here is querying the city table and finding all matches in the country table by using the identifying field in both those tables:

`country.code`  in your country table

`city.countrycode` in your city table

Whenever `country.code` = `city.countrycode` and `country.continent= 'Asia'`, you will be returned the sum of that population.

```
Select sum(city.population) from city inner join country on country.code = city.countrycode
where country.continent= 'Asia';
```

I also recommend you select the city the population count belongs to:

```
Select city.name, sum(city.population) from city inner join country on country.code = city.countrycode
where country.continent= 'Asia';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right code

```
Select sum(city.population) 
from city inner join country on country.code = city.countrycode
where country.continent= 'Asia';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(City.POPULATION) FROM City JOIN Country ON city.countrycode=country.code WHERE country.continent='Asia'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `;` at the end of the code.

```
Select sum(city.population) from city
where city.countrycode in (Select code from Country where continent = 'Asia');
```